# Angular JS : Scope values is not displayed in H1 tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this template:

Problem is that, i am able to ng-if, but statement

```
<h2>{{$verification.state}}</h2>
```

Does not provide any visible output (H2 tag is empty, without text)

```
<div ng-controller="UsersCtrl" ng-init="verifyUser()" class="jumbotron">
    <!- Verification Progres Icon-->
    <p class="lead">
        <i ng-if="verification.state == 'progress'" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-5x"></i>
        <i ng-if="verification.state == 'success'" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-5x"></i>
        <i ng-if="verification.state == 'error'" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-5x"></i>
    </p>
    <!- Verification Progres Text Description-->
    <h2>{{$verification.state}}</h2>
    <h2>{{$verification}}</h2>

    <!- Verification Progres Buttons-->
    <p>
        <a ng-if="verification.state == 'success'" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-href="#/users/login">
            Let me to login!
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        </a>

        <a ng-if="verification.state == 'error'" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-href="#/users/verify/token/{{verification.token}}">
            Try it again
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

In controller I'm setting up values to templet like this:

```
// set initial progress state
            $scope.verification = {
                state:"progress"
            };
```

How can I pass correctly and display values to the:

```
<h2>{{$verification.state}}</h2>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the dollar sign:

```
<h2>{{verification.state}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `{{$verification.state}}` use `{{verification.state}}` it should work